# Sum Columns based on Column Header in a SUMIFS formula

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a dashboard.

```
=IF(AND(Dashboard!G11="All", Dashboard!G18<>"All"), SUMIFS(INDEX(dtPages!C2:R,0,MATCH(Dashboard!G18,dtPages!C1:R1,0)), dtPages!T:T,Dashboard!X11,dtPages!U:U,Dashboard!X13), "SOMETHING")
```

This formula is supposed to SUMIFS a column whose header is equal to cell Dashboard!G18 based on some extra criteria.
I get an "Array arguments to SUMIFS are of different size" error. I understand what the error means, and I suspect that it's this that's causing it:

```
INDEX(dtPages!C2:R,0,MATCH(Dashboard!G18,dtPages!C1:R1,0))
```

Which is supposed to be part of this formula (I assumed that you can leave out the "SUM(" part, given that the SUMIFS should calculate the SUM.

```
SUM(INDEX(dtPages!C2:R,0,MATCH(Dashboard!G18,dtPages!C1:R1,0)))
```

Can anyone help?

I've also tried:

```
=IF(AND(Dashboard!G11="All", Dashboard!G18<>"All"), SUMIFS(SUMPRODUCT((dtPages!C2:R)*(dtPages!C1:R1=Dashboard!G18)), dtPages!T:T,Dashboard!X11,dtPages!U:U,Dashboard!X13), "ERROR")
```

By using

```
SUMPRODUCT((dtPages!C2:R)*(dtPages!C1:R1=Dashboard!G18))
```

Instead of the INDEX formula above. But I get an "Argument must be a range" error.

Comment: do you know about DSUM()?
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094281?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Try either*

```
=IF(AND(Dashboard!G11="All", Dashboard!G18<>"All"), SUMIFS(INDEX(dtPages!C:R,0,MATCH(Dashboard!G18,dtPages!C1:R1,0)), dtPages!T:T,Dashboard!X11,dtPages!U:U,Dashboard!X13), "SOMETHING")
```

***OR***

```
=IF(AND(Dashboard!G11="All", Dashboard!G18<>"All"), SUMIFS(INDEX(dtPages!C2:R,0,MATCH(Dashboard!G18,dtPages!C1:R1,0)), dtPages!T2:T,Dashboard!X11,dtPages!U2:U,Dashboard!X13), "SOMETHING")
```

Aligning `C2:R`, `T2:T`, `U2:U` within `dtPages` tab to have same row size to fix the `Array arguments to SUMIFS are of different size` error

***Alternate formula to try out***

```
=sum(ifna(filter(choosecols(dtPages!C2:R,xmatch(Dashboard!G18,dtPages!C1:R1)),dtPages!T2:T=Dashboard!X11,dtPages!U2:U=Dashboard!X13)))
```